# Synology: How install cloud station client on Ubuntu 14.04 or Mint 17

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, synology

How can i install cloud station client on Ubuntu 14.04 or Mint17? I have a DS215j and in the official [Download Center Synology](https://www.synology.com/en-uk/support/download/DS215j), only has Fedora installer. Should I download the Fedora package and convert the .rmp extension to .deb and then install it? Other possibilities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `alien` tool for converting alien binary packages into Debian packages or directly installing on Ubuntu system.

1. Install alien tool on your ubuntu box `$ sudo apt-get install alien`
2. Install .rpm package directly `$ sudo alien -i package_file.rpm`

For more info check [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/alien.1p.html) page of alien and community [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto)

---

**UPDATE**

Synology Cloud Station debian package version 3.2-3487 is not available but 3.2-3484 **is** !

Here is the link to Ubuntu [packages](http://dedl.synology.com/download/Tools/CloudStation/3.2-3484/Ubuntu/Installer/) choose your architecture and install it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but before asking the question on stackoverflow I saw the option to alien, but I saw that in some cases gives problems and the installation is not clean, and I can not risk that for this reason, cloud station don't run properly and i lose files.

Comment: Updated the answer with the link to latest available official deb package, check it out.